# animate elements in random sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I try to animate some buttons. A random string should be generated that the animated buttons arent always in the same sequence. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftjysy37/7/)

an example:

```
text = 1423
```

the first animated button is `btn1` then after one second `btn4` then after one second `btn2` then after one second `btn3`

the buttons:

```
<div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" style="" class="button"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" style="" class="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button name="btn3" type="submit" id="btn3" value="3" style="" class="button"></button>
    <button name="btn4" type="submit" id="btn4" value="4" style="" class="button"></button>
</div>
```

the javascript:

```
    var textArray = [];
var text = "";
function makeid()
{

    var possible = "1234";

    for( var i=0; i < 4; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
makeid();
textArray = text.split("");
console.log(textArray);

function animate1() {

$('#btn' + textArray[0]).animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 500);    
}
function animate2() {

$('#btn' + textArray[1]).animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 500);   
}
function animate3() {

  $('#btn' + textArray[2]).animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 500);    
}
function animate4() {

$('#btn' + textArray[3]).animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 500);
}

window.setTimeout(animate1, 1000);
window.setTimeout(animate2, 2000);
window.setTimeout(animate3, 3000);
window.setTimeout(animate4, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue about shuffling the `possible text`, because in your function there is a possibility that same number repeated. like: 2,2,2,1 or 4,4,4,4 and so on.

*you can use this shuffle function instead of your method of shuffling:*

```
function shuffleWord(word) {
    var shuffledWord = '';
    var charIndex = 0;
    word = word.split('');
    while (word.length > 0) {
        charIndex = word.length * Math.random() << 0;
        shuffledWord += word[charIndex];
        word.splice(charIndex, 1);
    }
    return shuffledWord;
}
```

See [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/2e2o6413/) of your example after updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate `backgroundColor` unless the `jQuery.Color` plugin is used, [jQuery animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color plugin is used).

And you allow duplicate IDs when creating the random order. Also, the code can be simplified.

```
var textArray = [];

function makeid() {
    var num;
    var possible = "1234";

    while(textArray.length < 4) {
        num = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

        if (textArray.indexOf(num) === -1) {
            textArray.push(num)
        }
    }
}

function animate(id, wait) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#btn' + id).animate({ width: '200'}, 500);
  }, wait);
}

makeid();
for (var i=0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
  animate(textArray[i], i * 1000)
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftjysy37/12/)